# Removing viruses in Snap folders

Tags: antivirus

I've run clam-av and have this message:

> /snap/inkscape/10154/lib/python3.8/site-packages/virtualenv/seed/wheels/embed/pip-20.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl: Win.Virus.Triusor-9950253-0 FOUND
> traverse_unlink: Failed to unlink: /snap/inkscape/10154/lib/python3.8/site-packages/virtualenv/seed/wheels/embed/pip-20.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
> Error:Read-only file system
> ERROR: Can't remove file '/snap/inkscape/10154/lib/python3.8/site-packages/virtualenv/seed/wheels/embed/pip-20.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl'

I'm (vaguely) aware that Snap uses a container system, so it makes sense to me that the AV software would be unable to modify files.

But what should I do about it?

Comment: Are you sure that's a true positive, and not a false one? I would be surprised if there was a virus in a snap application. I can advice that you go to the [snap forum](https://forum.snapcraft.io) and seek further assistance.

Comment: It's a false positive. Disable PUP in ClamAV

Comment: Thank you both.

Comment: Actually, PUP/PUA was not enabled at the time of the scan.

Comment: another hint: "Error:Read-only file system"  how would a virus save itself? >:)  This if possible would destroy inkscape: "Can't remove file '/snap/inkscape/10154/lib/python3.8/site-packages/virtualenv/seed/wheels/embed/pip-20.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl'" so a good thing it did not :P

Answer (score -1):

From `clamav.net`:

### ClamAV ® is the open-source standard for mail gateway-scanning software. High Performance ClamAV includes a multi-threaded scanner daemon, command-line utilities for on-demand file scanning and automatic signature updates.

It scans email (usually on a mail gateway), looking for Windows viruses **in email**. Using it to scan Linux is of no value, and can only produce false positives. Windows viruses don't run on Linux.

`aide` (Advanced Intrusion Detection Environment) is probably what you want. Read `man aide`.

Comment: Read `man aide` or https://linux.die.net/man/1/aide You generate the Aide database on your system. Aide compares against fhis. You can include or exclude filesystems